# Change UIView display order globally within view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, core-animation

Consider the following view hierarchy:

```
let bottomView = UIView()
addSubview(bottomView)

let bottomViewSubview = UIView()
bottomView.addSubview(bottomViewSubview)

let topView = UIView()
addSubview(topView)

// bottomViewSubview.displayOnTopOfTopView() - How?
```

I'm wondering if there is a possibility in UIKit without changing the view/subview hierarchy, to always display a subview of some view on top of all other views, including views that cover its superview. As far as I know CALayer.zIndex works only within UIView's sublayers, not globally as I need. And I can't change the hierarchy since I want to rely on it in everything else like subviews transforms.

I guess the only option is to create the new view, which is actually on top of the view hierarchy, and manually sync all the transforms for it to appear like it's someone's subview?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the view and use the `insert(_: at:)` function to move the views. Alternatively, `bringSubviewToFront(UIView)` and `sendSubviewToBack(UIView)` can be used. If you don't have a reference to the view you need to move, you can use the `subviews` property to find it.

```
bringSubviewToFront(bottomViewSubview)
```

Comment: It would mean changing the view hierarchy, and as I stated in the question I don't want to do it since I want to save other behaviors that come with a view being a subview of a certain view, like view/subview transforms. The only thing I want to change is display order.

Comment: You may need to separate view management then. The display order of subviews are determine by the order they are in the `subviews` array.